# Duplicate INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES occurs, skip that particular insert without error and go for next INSERT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table named TABLE1 having 2 columns (NO, NAME)

```
 CREATE TABLE TABLE1( NO NUMBER(3) NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL);
 
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TX ON TABLE1(NO,NAME);
```

I am trying to insert values as mentioned below:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(101, 'JOHN');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(102, 'MORN'); 
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'TONY');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'TONY');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'RONY');
```

As you see above, I have given one insert statement twice. Actually, above insert statements are working fine but when it comes 4th insert statement, it is throwing error which is expected. I am looking for INSERT INTO VALUES statement if duplicate insert statement comes it should skip that particular insert statement without showing error and go for next INSERT statement.

I tried using the below statements but its not working in Oracle SQL

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLE1 VALUES(101, 'JOHN');
INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLE1 VALUES(102, 'MORN'); 
INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'TONY');
INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'TONY');
INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'RONY');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an error log and redirect errors to that:

```sql
begin
  dbms_errlog.create_error_log (
    dml_table_name     => 'TABLE1'
  );
end;
/
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(101, 'JOHN') LOG ERRORS REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(102, 'MORN') LOG ERRORS REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'TONY') LOG ERRORS REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'TONY') LOG ERRORS REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'RONY') LOG ERRORS REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Outputs:

> | NO | NAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 101 | JOHN |
> | 102 | MORN |
> | 103 | RONY |
> | 103 | TONY |

and:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ERR$_TABLE1;
```

Outputs:

> | ORA_ERR_NUMBER$ | ORA_ERR_MESG$ | ORA_ERR_ROWID$ | ORA_ERR_OPTYP$ | ORA_ERR_TAG$ | NO | NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | ORA-00001: unique constraint (FIDDLE_TAXEGGNAZTFZWUNUZXOL.TX) violated<br> | *null* | I | *null* | 103 | TONY |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=404fdc10c844940ee8032980e30ced66)*

Comment: Can't we do anything with INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES statement without using ERR TABLE.. I am looking to avoid duplicates during initial phase of INSERT statements

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MERGE` statements to check for existing rows and only insert new ones:

```sql
MERGE INTO TABLE1 dst
USING (
  SELECT 101 AS no, 'JOHN' AS name FROM DUAL
) src
ON (dst.no = src.no AND dst.name = src.name)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (no, name) VALUES (src.no, src.name);

MERGE INTO TABLE1 dst
USING (
  SELECT 102 AS no, 'MORN' AS name FROM DUAL
) src
ON (dst.no = src.no AND dst.name = src.name)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (no, name) VALUES (src.no, src.name);

MERGE INTO TABLE1 dst
USING (
  SELECT 103 AS no, 'TONY' AS name FROM DUAL
) src
ON (dst.no = src.no AND dst.name = src.name)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (no, name) VALUES (src.no, src.name);

MERGE INTO TABLE1 dst
USING (
  SELECT 103 AS no, 'TONY' AS name FROM DUAL
) src
ON (dst.no = src.no AND dst.name = src.name)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (no, name) VALUES (src.no, src.name);

MERGE INTO TABLE1 dst
USING (
  SELECT 103 AS no, 'RONY' AS name FROM DUAL
) src
ON (dst.no = src.no AND dst.name = src.name)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (no, name) VALUES (src.no, src.name);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Outputs:

> | NO | NAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 101 | JOHN |
> | 102 | MORN |
> | 103 | RONY |
> | 103 | TONY |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=61347e4aca5d42e2437b11a5796e8229)*

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `INSERT` statements in a PL/SQL anonymous block and catch the `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX` exception:

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(101, 'JOHN');
EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
  NULL;
END;
/

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(102, 'MORN');
EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
  NULL;
END;
/

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'TONY');
EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
  NULL;
END;
/

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'TONY');
EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
  NULL;
END;
/

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'RONY');
EXCEPTION WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Outputs:

> | NO | NAME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 101 | JOHN |
> | 102 | MORN |
> | 103 | RONY |
> | 103 | TONY |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=19a6e9120d69bae820e025882d21f32c)*

Comment: Show off, from MTO :). Thansk for the such a nice information, really.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#CHDEGDDG) hint in your `INSERT` statements to skip such rows. But it works [much slower](https://iusoltsev.wordpress.com/2013/12/29/ignore_row_on_dupkey_index/) than plain insert with check or error logging table.

> ```
> begin
> INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(101, 'JOHN');
> INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(102, 'MORN'); 
> INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'TONY');
> INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'TONY');
> INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'RONY');
> end;/
> ```

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (FIDDLE_FQMLAYWWHWTRJVYNUNXG.TX) violated
> ORA-06512: at line 5

> ```
> begin
> INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(TABLE1(NO,NAME))*/ INTO TABLE1 VALUES(101, 'JOHN');
> INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(TABLE1(NO,NAME))*/ INTO TABLE1 VALUES(102, 'MORN');
> INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(TABLE1(NO,NAME))*/ INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'TONY');
> INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(TABLE1(NO,NAME))*/ INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'TONY');
> INSERT /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(TABLE1(NO,NAME))*/ INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'RONY');
> end;/
> ```

> 1 rows affected

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=44eae426bf06bd7d9c1acc981fc7a39e)*